# Reading XLS file with OLEDB: Excel worksheet is split up in multiple sheets

Tags: c#, excel, ole

I want to read the data from an Excel file (XLS format). When opening the sample file with MS Office 2013 I see five sheets.
[image: Excel file]

```
OleDbConnection Conn_Excel = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
      + "Data Source=\"" + importFolder + job.GetString("filename") 
      + "\";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
  Conn_Excel.Open();
  DataTable dtSchema = Conn_Excel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
try {
      for (int i = 0; i < dtSchema.Rows.Count; i++) {
        sheet1 = dtSchema.Rows[i].Field<string>("TABLE_NAME").Substring(1, 
            dtSchema.Rows[i].Field<string>("TABLE_NAME").Length - 2); 
        //remove apostrophs
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sheet: " + sheet1);
        tablenames.Add(sheet1, sheet1);
      }
      if (!tablenames.ContainsKey("Datenimport (data)$")) {
        ret.messages = "Worksheet 'Datenimport (data)' not found";
        ret.success = false;
        return ret;
      }
      sql = @"SELECT * FROM [Datenimport (data)$] ";
      MySqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, Conn_Excel);
      Excel_DataReader = MySqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The output delivers following results:

```
Sheet: Beschreibung (description)$
Sheet: Beschreibung (description)$'Druckbereic
Sheet: Beschreibung (description)$'Z_1C961D83_5305_47A2_AD32_2C8B6A60
Sheet: Beschreibung (description)$'Z_2904AF4C_E295_49E4_901C_31732223
Sheet: Beschreibung (description)$'Z_4257C5D2_6B17_49AB_A281_39B84DF9
Sheet: Beschreibung (description)$'Z_646ECE2D_4A3F_487E_8B08_FD7FB4CB
Sheet: Datenimport (data)$
Sheet: Datenimport (data)$'
Sheet: Datenimport (data)$'_140709iniMediGlobNK181733
Sheet: Datenimport (data)$'Z_1C961D83_5305_47A2_AD32_2C8B6A6080EC_#wv
Sheet: Datenimport (data)$'Z_2904AF4C_E295_49E4_901C_31732223FCA6_#wv
Sheet: Datenimport (data)$'Z_4257C5D2_6B17_49AB_A281_39B84DF912E3_#wv
Sheet: EDIFACT Codes$
Sheet: EDIFACT Codes$'Druckbereic
Sheet: Legende (legend)$
Sheet: Legende (legend)$'Druckbereic
Sheet: Legende (legend)$'Z_1C961D83_5305_47A2_AD32_2C8B6A6080EC_#wvu#
Sheet: Legende (legend)$'Z_2904AF4C_E295_49E4_901C_31732223FCA6_#wvu#
Sheet: Legende (legend)$'Z_4257C5D2_6B17_49AB_A281_39B84DF912E3_#wvu#
Sheet: Legende (legend)$'Z_646ECE2D_4A3F_487E_8B08_FD7FB4CBA8FA_#wvu#
Sheet: Matrix MG$
```

I tried to save the file as XLSX and save back as XLS to create a completely new file, but this didn't help. 
When I read the sheet named 'Datenimport (data)' I get only 66 rows but in Excel the sheet inherits about 1000 rows. So I guess the data must be in the other (hidden) sheets.
Do I use wrong parameters when opening the OLE DB Connection?

Kind regards

Comment: How many rows are present in the first sheet?

Comment: It inherits about 1000 rows